# Are multiple blob's write actions allowed on Google Chrome's FileSystem API?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome, filesystems

I am playing with the FileSystem API in Google Chrome 16 but can't write more than once blob (without reopen the file for appending). Seems like the file is closed after the first write.

For example:

```
var blob = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
blob.append('one');
fileWriter.write(blob.getBlob('text/plain'));

var blob2 = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
blob2.append('two');
fileWriter.write(blob2.getBlob('text/plain'));
```

gives a **_Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM File Exception 7_**

The W3 doc says about [FileWriter](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html): ***"This interface expands on the FileSaver interface to allow for multiple write actions, rather than just saving a single Blob."***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specification, you are not allowed to use a writer *when it's busy writing*:

> `write`
>
> 1. If `readyState` is `WRITING`, throw a `FileException` with error code `INVALID_STATE_ERR` and terminate this overall series of steps.

Since the writer is asynchronous, you have to wait using a callback:

```
// write first blob

fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
  // write second blob
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it was my fault. I was trying to write before the event was raised.